# How to make discord bot say a string/phrase in a voice channel. (Like a text-to-speech thing)

Tags: audio, discord, discord.js

Someone I know told me I should use some sort of npm package that sends streams then use `VoiceConnection.playStream` but told me he doesn't know any packages that do so.

I am using discord.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [say](https://github.com/Marak/say.js) to generate the audio file from a text, export it, and then play the sound in a voice channel.

```
const say = require('say');
...
function tts(voiceChannel, text) {
    if (!FS.existsSync('./temp')){
        FS.mkdirSync('./temp');
    }
    const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    const soundPath = `./temp/${timestamp}.wav`;
    say.export(text, null, 1, soundPath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }else{
            voiceChannel.join().then((connection) => {
                connection.playFile(soundPath).on('end', () => {
                    connection.disconnect();
                    FS.unlinkSync(soundPath);
                }).on('error', (err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                    connection.disconnect();
                    FS.unlinkSync(soundPath);
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately say.export() [doesn't work on Linux](https://github.com/Marak/say.js#feature-matrix).

Comment: Note you have to define `const FS = require('fs');`

Answer (score -2):

Not exactly sure if you mean TTS or using Voice Channel directly :(

But if you meant TTS:

> ```
> message.channel.send("Meow! I'm a baby loli kitten!", {
>  tts: true
> })
> ```

If you need a package, you could try [text-to-speech-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-to-speech-js), hope I helped in any way~ meow!

Comment: I want it to join a voice channel and speak tts. (For example, someone uses a "/say hello" command, the bot says "hello" with a text-to-speech voice in a voice channel)